# how to remove index.php from url in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I had some big issues with removing the index.php. As a general rule the .htaccess below has been tested on several servers and generally works:

how to remove index.php below link in codeigniter
http://localhost/test/index.php/home/plans

Comment: Which htaccess below? There's a number of questions covering this already; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809373/remove-index-php-from-url-codeigniter?rq=1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201409/how-to-remove-index-php-from-codeigniter-url?rq=1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155333/remove-index-php-from-url-codeigniter-2?rq=1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9368543/remove-index-php-from-codeigniter-urls?rq=1

Comment: create .htaccess file in your root folder and past this [code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43364031/redirection-issues-in-live-server/43364089#43364089)

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove index.php From URL - Codeigniter 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155333/remove-index-php-from-url-codeigniter-2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Have to add .htaccess file in you root folder .

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|(.*)\.swf|forums|images|css|downloads|jquery|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

Save this file as .htaccess in System Folder